# How to lock a view as the user scrolls

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new-ish to iphone development and I am trying to figure out how I can fix a view after it has reached a the top of the screen when a user scrolls a window. Then the view would unlock when the window is scrolled down again to go back to its original position.  Ive seen this on on a few apps like instagram (with the user name separators).

Does this design pattern have a specific name?

---

An example (not iPhone though) can be seen on http://mashable.com/  -- Look at "The New Stuff", "The Next Big Thing", and "What's Hot" bar.  See how it locks as you scroll down

Answer (score 2):

My solution for you is

1. create a `UITableView`
2. create a `UIView` separately which will be used as fixed table header
3. setup the table's `tableHeaderView` property to conform the `UIView's` frame
4. as UITableView is inherited from `UIScrollView` you can rely on `scrollViewDidScroll` method in which I properly adjust my fixed header as Y coordinate changes when scrolling the table.

There can be other similar solution for this too but a strenght of this particular solution is that you can manipulate the fixed header's gui element throughout the scrolling easily.

An example is always better than writing down the details so I created for you (and hopefully for others here at SO) a sample project (of course quick'n dirty), which you can find here at github:
https://github.com/codedad/SO_Fixed_TableHeader_iOS

Comment: Thanks for the code example.  But in this example the view is always the first element, fixed header... In my explanation I want it to be more down the view, say the third element.

Comment: It is up to your requirement where you want this header locked, because 1) you have to implement tableView:viewForHeaderInSection to assign eg. the 3rd section a custom view 2) modify properly my example, especially scrollViewDidScroll where you have the only possibility to change something on the view according to the scrolling.   Currently I dont have more time but after holiday ;) I try to modify my example..

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you're trying to achieve something like the `UITableView` in the Contacts app?

It uses the sections of the `UITableView` for the sorted letters and displays them always on top.

Have a look a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249261/ios-uitableview-section-header-anchor-to-top-of-table) and [create custom section headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section).

Comment: I've added that you can create custom sections using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611374/customize-uitableview-header-section)